# Filter pd.DataFrame by string in header and string in column of the found header

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get my head around a way where I can select / filter columns that contain in the header a specific string and another string within the column.

I am a little bit confused with the way I could quickly select the columns and the rows concerning the selected columns.

Assume the following dataframe df:

```
    Country/Region  Record ID
0   France          118
1   France          110
2   United Kingdom  146
3   United Kingdom  836
4   France          944
```

and I am thinking something like:

condition_1 --> filter the columns that contain "Country" in the header
condition_2 --> filter the rows where the country is "France"

Is it possible to do it with one `.loc[]` and/or with a def or a lambda function? I need to use it multiply for several combinations and conditions within my process.

I have tried to combine the following somehow without success:

`country_condition = lambda df, string: df.filter(regex=string)`

`df.loc[country_condition==True, :]` or `df[df.filter(regex='Country') == 'France']`

so any help will be appreciated.

I want to be able to give the string that the header will need to include (here 'Country) and the string that the rows of this column will need to include (here 'France') so that I get:

```
    Country/Region  Record ID
0   France          118
1   France          110
4   France          944
```

Comment: `df.filter` operates on the columns only when you pass `regex` (it's basically just a faster way of saying `df[[i for i in df.columns if re.match(regex, i)]]`). Use standard subsetting like `df[df['Country/Region'] == 'France']`.

Comment: My dataframes columns won't always have this header. I only know the header will contain the string 'Country'. This is why I try to automate it.

Comment: Rename them all to have the same column name.

Comment: I won't have this opportunity with the real datasets. The headers will vary inconsistently to always perform ```.rename(columns=)```. The only consistent thing is that the string 'Country' will be part of the header.

Comment: So just apply a renaming based on regular expressions instead of specifying a literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, which should work with multiple columns with `Country` in the header:

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='Country').eq('France').all(axis=1), :]
```

Output:

```
  Country/Region  Record ID
0         France        118
1         France        110
4         France        944
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I need to study this chain ^_^

Comment: Would it be possible to have more than one countries within ```eq()```? I tried ```eq('France|Spain')```
 for example and it does not work. I cannot find something similar online.

Comment: @Newbielp: A possibility can be: `df.loc[df.filter(like='Country').isin(['France', 'Spain']).all(axis=1), :]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the column name and value in that column you want to look up, you can simply use `df[df['Country/Region'] == 'France']`

But I think your question is more complicated than that.

First condition, we need the list of column names.

```
cols = [x if 'Country' in x for x in df.cols]
```

Next let's check for 'France' on any of these columns. Since cols is a list let's check one by one and concatenate the results.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for col in cols:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df[df[col] == 'France']])
```

Full code example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country/Region': ['France', 'France', 'Spain'], 'Record ID': [120, 240, 360]})
cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'Country' in x]

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for col in cols:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df[df[col] == 'France']])

print(new_df)
```

prints:

```
  Country/Region  Record ID
0         France        120
1         France        240
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to simply keep your data as is and query in a standard way:

```
df[df['Country/Region'] == 'France']
```

What `df.filter(regex=...)` does is select data frame columns that match the regex. It is identical to running `df[[i for i in df.columns if re.match(..., i)]]`. But you say you have multiple columns that might not all start with the same name: `df.filter` may run into the issue where there are multiple matches.

```
>>> df0 = pd.DataFrame({'country/adjfkl': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country/a1395d': ['B', 'C', 'D']})
>>> pd.concat([d[lambda e: e.filter(regex='^country').eq('B').any(axis=1)] for d in [df0, df1]])
  country/adjfkl country/a1395d
1              B            NaN
0            NaN              B
```

The filter result can be dimensionally reduced with any across (ie horizontally). I can't entirely say why you would do this, however, inasmuch as you'll be left with inconsistent columns.

It would be better to just rename them ab initio:

```
>>> pd.concat(
...     [d.rename(
...         columns=lambda s: re.sub('^country.*', 'country_name', s)).loc[
...         lambda e: e['country_name'] == 'B', :
...     ] for d in [df0, df1]]
... )
  country_name
1            B
0            B
```